# Angular prevent filter call in ng-mouseover

Tags: angularjs, mouseevent

I have Angular web application and there are links like this:

```
<a id="{{ model.name }}" href="{{ model.url }}" 
   ng-bind="model.name | active_menu: model.name" 
   ng-click="click_on_model(model.name)"> 
   ng-mouseover="hover(model.name")
</a>
```

Why everytime `active_menu` filter calls when `ng-mouseover` executes? How to prevent it and execute filter only before rendering.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS is unable to predict that the return value of a filter is the same every time it is executed. So calling *anything* on the scope will re-trigger all the visible filters. Although Angular is very very fast in general, this can be bad for performance if you have used some expensive filters, but it can also cause [infinite digest loops](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24rootScope/infdig), which are quite annoying.

For these reasons I always try to avoid using filters. In your case you probably just need to display a menu item in a different way if it's active.  I've made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YJ4MfgAVBm9ppJtRzzdF?p=preview) that demonstrates this behaviour in more detail.